# Angular RxJS null value after being unloaded

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created an observable that emits arrays.
If I use it in a template, like: `{{ ob | async }}` it works fine.

However, if I do:

```
<div *ngIf="is">{{ ob | async | json }}</div>
<div *ngIf="!is">{{ ob | async | json }}</div>
```

The first time I see the correct JSON, but if I flip `is`, I see `null`.

Observable [creation code](https://gist.github.com/AmitMY/4dbfaf82b159092810252d44dcedec88#file-geofire-provider-ts-L79):

```
return Rx.Observable.create((observer: Rx.Observer<Array<GeoFireLocation>>) => {
  let locations: Array<GeoFireLocation> = [];

  geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
    locations = this.insertIntoSortedArray({
      key, distance,
      coordinates: {
        latitude: location[0],
        longitude: location[1]
      }
    }, locations);
    observer.next(locations);
  });

  geoQuery.on('key_exited', (key) => {
    locations = locations.filter(location => location.key === key);
    observer.next(locations);
  });
}).finally(() => geoQuery.cancel());
```

Comment: What is under `is` variable? How do you set up its value?

Comment: A toggle I flip `true`/`false`. Defaults to `true`, it shows the first row in first time, but if I flip it shows `null`, if I flip again, `null` again

Comment: Are you sure that there are any emissions after you switch `is`?

Comment: With `*ngIf` the subscription via `async` doesn't until `*ngIf` condition is `true` so if you switch `is` and then `ob` doesn't emit anything you won't see any result.

Comment: @martin It should emit the last value, which it does, I just performed cleanup in the wrong place, shouldn't be in `finally`, but somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the `finally` is being called whenever I flip the `is` variable.

No idea how to cleanup the observable, but at least I found the problem here.